# What is the best task scheduling approach in Plone 4?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, plone

We need to schedule some tasks in Plone 4 (notify users after n days of inactivity, etc.). What is the best way to do it? Is there something in Plone or maybe an old cron job? I would like to avoid [cron4plone](http://plone.org/products/cron4plone).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use the built-in [`<clock-server>` functionality](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/asyncronoustasks.html#clock-server) in zope.conf; list them in the `zope-conf-additional` option of `plone.recipe.zope2instance`:

```
zope-conf-additional =
  <clock-server>
    method /Plone/path/to/callable
    period 7200
    user username-to-invoke-method-with
    password password-for-user
    host localhost
  </clock-server>
```

The above snippet will call `/Plone/path/to/callable` every 2 hours, with the Host header set to `localhost` with the configured user and password.

The clock-server was added to Zope 2.10; before this it was a separate product by Chris McDonough. I generally created dedicated views for such tasks.

The alternative is to use a cron job to call either a view (usually with `wget` or `cron`) or a [zopectl command line script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511955/can-you-define-an-entry-point-in-your-plone-product-to-run-a-script-as-if-it-was/10514765#10514765). I use this when I need precise control over *when* the script needs to be executed, such as at midnight every day.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was planning to use.